# C# API : How to use access_token in other API

Tags: c#, api, oauth, oauth-2.0, owin

I'm developping an API which return `PDF` (`WsDocument`). To secure this API I developped second API which create `oauth` `access_token` (`WsOauth`). I have no problem to create my `access_token`. But when I pass my `access_token` in the header of my `WsDocument` I have have this message:

> access denied

I have already tried to pass my `access_token` whith different syntax for the header. I really dont know what can I tried next.

Here the code to call my WsDocument :

```
[Route("api/test/{username}/{password}/{type}/{loc}/{docnumber}")]
[Route("ws/get_document")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage getDocument(string type, int docnumber, int loc, string username, string password)
{
    //Variable
    HttpResponseMessage zresponse = null;

    //Récupération du token
    HttpResponseMessage ztokenresponse = checkAuthentification(username, password, loc);
    var jsonresult = ztokenresponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    var deserializedjsonResult = JObject.Parse(jsonresult);
    string ztoken = deserializedjsonResult["access_token"].ToString();

    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        if (ztoken != null)
        {
            //Aout du token dans le header pour pouvoir accéder à la ressource
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", ztoken);

            //Appel de la fonction getDocumentA4
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44308/");
            string requesturi = "ws/get_documentA4/" + username + "/" + password + "/" + type + "/" + loc + "/" + docnumber;

            zresponse = client.GetAsync(requesturi).Result;
        }
    }
    return zresponse;
}
```

Here the code called previously

```
[Authorize]
[Route("ws/get_documentA4/{username}/{password}/{type}/{loc}/{docnumber}")]
[Route("ws/get_documentA4")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage getDocumentA4(string type, int docnumber, int loc, string username, string password)
{
    HttpResponseMessage zresponse = null;
    DocumentA4Model zdocumentmodel = new DocumentA4Model();

    IServiceDatabase zservice = WebApiConfig._allConnectedLocation.Find(x => x.Name == loc.ToString()).Database;

    if (zservice != null)
    {
        //Retourne le document en fonction des paramètres insérés
        zdocumentmodel = DocumentWSModel.getDocument(zservice, type, loc, docnumber);
    }

    if (File.Exists(DocumentWSModel.Doc_file_path))
    {
        //Retourne le fichier PDF
        zresponse = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        zresponse.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(DocumentWSModel.Doc_file_path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
        zresponse.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        zresponse.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = zdocumentmodel.Doc_file_name;
        zresponse.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");

        return zresponse;
    }
    return null;
}
```

EDIT : When I call my function in my `WsOauth` I have access to my `ressource`. I suppose problems come from my header and how I pass my token to my `WsDocument`.

Comment: Have you tried making the request through software like Postman to test the api call? And are you able to post the API method that is being called?

Comment: Even with postman it doesn't work. I tried to pass manually my token in postman but it doesn't work. I have already post the API method that is called, it's the second block of code. My first method called the second method wich isin the WsDocument

Comment: Do you have the full error or stack trace being returned? It looks like you are attaching the token correctly but an invalid token would normally return a 401 Unauthorized or 403 Forbidden

Comment: It returns "401 Unauthorized". But if my token is invalid how can you explain that I can have an acces to my API method when I put it in my WsOauth and not in my WsDocument